# Right-align Image using bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <img src="image/t.png " class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 ">
        <img src="image/b.png " class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want `b.png` image to be right-align.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just need to add `.pull-right` class.
So it will be like this example :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <img src="image/t.png " class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 ">
        <img src="image/b.png " class="pull-right img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add the `pull-right` bootstrap class

```
<div class="col-xs-9 ">
    <img src="image/b.png " class="img-responsive pull-right">
</div>
```